# What is the point of two types of module files (interface and implementation) in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

When I want to export something I write `export void foo();` I can implement it in the same module file or do it in a separate one. But what is the point of formally distinguishing these files (`export module mymodule` vs `module mymodule`) when, anyway, I can have any number of the latter type. Wouldn't be enough to just put `export` keyword before the thing I want to make public and not need to bother with special interface files?

Comment: Isn't the answer analogous to "what is the point of header files in C++"?

Comment: You are _allowed_ to publish an interface separately, long before you even started any implementation. Is that not good?

Comment: @BoP I don't argue with the idea of keeping the interface part separate if it is desired. I'm asking Why do I need a special TYPE of module file to export something.

Comment: @Botje No. In *.h/*.cpp case client explicitly decides to import particular file (*.h). When importing a module client doesn't choose any file. They just import a module by module name.

Comment: C++ compilers supported creating modules long before C++20.  Problem was, they all did it a different way, using non-standard extensions to their language implementation.  Standardizing it was long overdue.  Making everybody equally unhappy just takes a long time in the ISO committee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point, the build system sees that some file says `import MyModule;`. When it sees that, the build system needs to go find the module for `MyModule`.

If `MyModule` has not yet been built, the build system needs to build it. To do that, it has to (among other things) scan all of the known source files in your project to see which ones are used to build `MyModule`. But the most important thing is that it needs to figure out which file it specifically needs to build in order for `import MyModule` to work right now.

That process works best and fastest if the system only needs to look for a single file to build (this way, the system can pre-process everything with a quick scanner to find all of those files). So the module system provides that: for any particular module, there is the primary module interface which defines *everything* that is exported by a module. Building that module may provoke the compilation of other modules, but we know which file has to be finished building before `import MyModule` can work.

Now sticking *everything* a module can export into just one file is not the best idea. So in many cases, you'll have multiple files that export stuff, and you'll `export import` them in your main `MyModule` primary interface file. But since module names are global, we don't want dozens of tiny module names cluttering up the namespace.

Enter module partitions: These are module interface files whose module names are "namespaced" within a specific module. Module interface files can include other partitions, but only those within the same module. And obviously, the graph of partition inclusion must be acyclic.

But that leaves us with a small problem. Let's say you have a partition that defines a class that gets exported to the primary module interface. But you don't want to put the implementation of those member functions in that partition file. So... where does it go?

I mean, you could put it in another partition that doesn't get imported by anybody. But if that partition doesn't get imported... why bother giving it a partition name? It'd be best if you can communicate *immediately* that this "partition" *cannot* be included.

Enter module implementation units. They are part of a specific module, and therefore they can import *partitions* of that module. But they cannot *themselves* be imported by anyone.

That's what they're for.

But note that the build system knows that it doesn't need to build module implementation units in order to completely build the module. It only needs to build the primary module interface file and any partitions included by it (directly or indirectly). This allows module rebuilding to be as fast as possible if you put your implementations into implementation units.

Lastly, module implementation units (and interface units) have access to any names that they import from a partition which the partition does not *export*. These module-local names are only accessible within the module.

Comment: Can you tell if everything related to modules is already standardized and all the popular compilers (lets say CLang/GCC/MSVC) already implemented everything related to modules in this standard way? Because some time ago I tried to learn modules and it seemed to me that every compiler had its own way of working with modules. For example the only way I found for automatically converting regular old-style header to header unit (which is module) in CLang was through using `.modulemap` file types which has totally CLang specific syntax.

Comment: @Arty: Clang had an old module system which has nothing to do with C++20 modules (anything talking about "modulemap"s are talking about their old stuff). Clang does not [advertise support for C++20 modules as of yet](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). They have some degree of "partial" support, but not actual support.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It’s not quite “nothing”: Clang’s header units are part of the standard alongside MSVC’s global module fragment.  The module map is in that interpretation just how you control the “implementation-defined set of headers” ([module.import]/5) that are importable.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Is there any documentation on the relationship between these module maps and how Clang is implementing C++20 modules? Because everything I've seen from Clang about module map files relates specifically to their old module functionality, which is not equivalent to C++20 module definitions.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I did say “in that interpretation”.  Their feature is not yet even a subset of the standard feature, but the module map isn’t what makes their feature non-standard.

Comment: @DavisHerring: I was using "module map" as a marker, an indicator that any Clang documentation using this term is *not* talking about C++20 modules. Maybe their eventual C++20 module implementation will use some kind of "module map" file, but I was only using it as a way to tell the difference between the Clang feature and the C++ feature.

Answer (score 9):

Module implementation units can use things with **module linkage** (neither `export` nor `static`) in their module’s interface.  If all module units were both interface and implementation units, some mechanism would be needed to deal with the **circularity** of this access.

The way this is implemented is that module-linkage entities are included in the compiled module interface file: it is helpful to the implementation to know **immediately** whether that sort of processing is needed for a translation unit.  (This is similar to needing to know to what module a file belongs in order to mangle its symbol names properly.)

Moreover, requiring that all parts of the module interface be declared upfront (in the primary interface or in an interface partition that it recruits) avoids needing to **“link”** the interface results of multiple independent module units into one CMI to be consumed by importers.  The fact that module implementation units can’t affect importers except via linking in different symbol definitions is also beneficial to the build system: importers do not need to be **recompiled** when module implementation units but not interface units change.